# Select faces within a selection

Tags: selection-tools

Checked for similar answers.

What would be the easiest way to select the faces within the already selected faces.

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, the [hover-<kbd>L</kbd>] and [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>] operations select contiguous faces by visibility, not underlying geometry.. so.. in Edit Mode..

- <kbd>H</kbd> hide the selected perimeter faces
- With the cursor over an inner face, <kbd>L</kbd>. Or, having selected an inner face, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> unhide the perimeter faces again

Hiding geometry is more useful than it might seem, at first.

Comment: Thank you Robin